# How to set hyperlink field with SharePoint Designer WorkFlow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, hyperlink

I'd like to know how to set with a WF sharepoint 2010 and hyperlink column.
When i set a value, it's only for url and i can't set description.

Do you have a sample or tutorial to do this?

Answer (score 6):

To do this you need to use the build a dynamic string action. In it, you construct your url, description value information. Example, http://google.com, Google. The comma and space are important.

Then you use this variable in your update action to set the value. Upon completion of the workflow, you should see it set properly.

Comment: I can't find `Dynamic String` in the list of actions that SPD can do for Sharepoint Online (2013/2016).

Comment: in the 2013 engine for 2013/2016/SPO, it should just be set workflow variable and that will give you the dynamic string builder window

Answer (score 1):

Great idea, but I had to do a bit more trickery.

Background, I’m writing a custom workflow in SPD against a SP list located in SharePoint Online as part of MS' Office 365 solution.

First, create a column in your list that is type Hyperlink. Select URL as the sub-type.
Second, in SPD, do these steps:

1. Add a new action for Set Field
2. In that action, click on the word field and select any text column. Title is a good one. It doesn't matter because we'll change the selected column in a bit.
3. Click the 3 dots to open the dynamic string builder.
4. Add the URL proper as the first part, e.g. `https://your_SharePoint_domain/...`  Note: this string can include any suffix like `/editform.aspx?ID=1&DefaultView=Admin.` It can also be a workflow variable with all of that in it. Just make sure it is a valid URL. Add a comma and space and your display text. As said from the answer above, the space is important. If you used a workflow variable, the string might look like Variable: `[%yourWorkflowVar %]`, Text to Display. If just a string, it might look like www.google.com, Google.
5. Click **OK** to close the string builder dialog.
6. IMPORTANT: click the column name immediately to the right of Set and scroll through the drop box to find your URL column. You will notice that the string you built above remains intact.
7. If you ever need to edit your string, repeat the above. Reason: SPD forces the Edit Hyperlink dialog which will not have a dynamic string build function.

That's it.

Comment: Tried that but have received an error message:
I’m trying the solution but receive a suspended workflow with the error message saying:
`…The input source is not correctly formatted. —> System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered unexpected character ‘h’. at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlException exception)…`

Any suggestions/ideas on that?

Comment: @evictorov sounds like your workflow is treating the Hyperlink field as a Dictionary. Are you using an SP2013 Workflow? The above instructions are for 2010.

Comment: @ChrisOdegard yes, I'm using 2013 workflow. Any help appreciated!