# SP2010 - 2019 How can I put in a hyperlink that is based on the user entry of that field or another field?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, hyperlink

How do you create an item that takes a user entered ticket number and concatenate that with a URL to create a hyperlink to the ticket in the ticketing system.

User enters ticket #  **123456**

URL to ticket system:  https://Ticket/Display.html?id=<**ticket#**>

Best answer would hide this url and allow users to click the **12345** number and open the website to that ticket.

Other options???

I'm just getting back into Sharepoint and this server will be upgraded to SP2019 in the next few months so I need the solution to be simple :) and I need it to survive the upgrades  (2010 > 2013 > 2016 > 2019).

Answer (score 0):

Use the SharePoint designer workflow or if you have Nintex workflow.  Create a column in the task list name as something open task with hyperlink type. Using workflow after creating the task, update this new column(hyperlink) with the SiteURL +taskid (what user entered).. this will be linking to the task but this link should be displayed just as the number like "1234567" (the task number what you have mentioned), now you can even send this link as an email to the user as a notification.

The above solution could be achieved using the calculated field as well but there is a limitation in that - after the **June 2017 Public Update (PU)** we cannot add custom HTML in the calculated column for **SharePoint 2013** & **2016** version onwards.

Please refer to the below Microsoft article for the calculated field limitation in SharePoint:

[Handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)

Comment: I noted in my initial comments that this is SP2010 but would need to be upgradeable through to the current version.  I didn't however note that this is NOT Sharepoint online.

Comment: Better you go with the workflow which is upgradeable to the next version

Comment: As I said I'm am just getting back into SP.  Do you know of a good BRIEF article on setting up a workflow? and also specifically to do this?

Comment: You can refer to the below links :https://www.google.com/amp/s/sharepointmustard.com/2017/09/27/workflow-to-update-hyperlink-display-text/amp/

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161665/how-to-set-hyperlink-field-with-sharepoint-designer-workflow

Answer (score 0):

You could try calculate column.

[image]

Additional steps would need for SharePoint 2016/2019

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/01/format-calculated-column-as-hyperlink-in-sharepoint-online.html

Comment: There is a limitation in the calculated column in the SharePoint 2013 onwards after the June 2017 PU update, here is a Microsoft documentation: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: I created a calculated field that resulted in the following: <a target='_blank' href='https://myapp.mydomain.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=555555'>Show Details</a>.    But the entire string is showing instead of just "Show Details" and you can't click it to launch the app.

Comment: As per Microsoft above article, this does not work after June 2017 public cu update from sp 2013 version onwards.. yes you are right, I also couldn't render as short text link finally did through workflow

Comment: I'm currently using SP2010 so it should work shouldn't it?